# Why my Epson Xp 322 can't print on 220 gr paper?

Tags: printing

I've bought "DecaDry" business card paper, weight 220gr.

I've tried to print tons of time but printer can't load paper and result me "jam paper".

How to set printer driver to see 220gr paper ?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.epson.co.uk/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/faq/1035/13671

Comment: That's not depending on settings, but the capability of the printer to deal with the paper. Probably your paper is too "hard" for the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Card stock is often a problem due to thickness and stiffness.  It isn't clear from the online manual whether your printer has a paper tray underneath in addition to the rear feed tray, but use the rear feed tray, which is close to a straight path.  You might need to feed one sheet at a time.  Make sure the sheet doesn't have any curl.

It looks like the printer may adjust itself to the paper thickness, as well as the surface finish.  The paper type is specified on the control panel, but it looks like everything is referenced to Epson's own papers.  If your card stock is photo quality, with a shiny surface, I would select one of the photo papers, probably "glossy".  If it isn't shiny, they use the "matte" setting for their own matte heavy weight paper.

Note, though, the the printer specs state a maximum of 90 gr paper.  I suspect their own photo paper is heavier than that, but you're trying card stock that is 2 1/2 times the maximum thickness, so it might not be usable with your printer.  Here is a [link](ftp://download.epson-europe.com/pub/download/3789/epson378930eu.pdf) to the online manual.

Just an aside, inkjet printing is not a great approach to business cards.  Even archival inks and paper don't hold up well to handling, the environment, or getting wet.  If your recipients don't treat them well, the cards' appearance won't reflect well on you.  It's pretty cheap to have cards commercially printed, and they will retain a professional look much better.